# How to avoid force close application in Android

Tags: android, exception, mobile

I've tried searching the internet for solution unfortunately I could not find the answer. I tried using try catch to catch error exception but still it won't work.
Here's my code. I have private class LoginTask

```
private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,JSONObject> {


    private String[] privateCredentials;
    private String privateRequest;
    private String errorMessage = "";
    //initialize all here
    //constructor
    LoginTask(String[] credentials,String request) {
        this.privateRequest = request;
        this.privateCredentials = credentials;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(this.privateRequest=="login"){
            try {
                String response = result.getString("status");

                if(response.equals("ok")){
                    onLoginSuccess(result.getString("username"),result.getString("full_name"),result.getInt("user_id"));

                }else{
                    onLoginFails();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                if(errorMessage!=""){
                    Toast ts;
                    ts = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,errorMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    ts.show();
                }
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }




    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

        String result = "";
        JSONObject resultObj = null;
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        JSONObject cred = new JSONObject();

        if(this.privateRequest=="login"){

            try {

                cred.put("username", this.privateCredentials[0]);
                cred.put("password", this.privateCredentials[1]);

                URL url = new URL(params[0]);


                con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                ;
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                con.setDoInput(true);
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.connect();
                OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
                outputStream.write(cred.toString().getBytes());
                InputStream stream = con.getInputStream();
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                //get the result
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
                resultObj = jsonObj;

                // return buffer.toString();


            }catch (JSONException e) {
                errorMessage = e.getMessage();
                final String error = e.getMessage();

                //e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        //ErrorDialog(e.getMessage());
                        Toast ts;
                        ts = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        ts.show();
                    }
                });
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
               errorMessage = e.getMessage();
                final String error = e.getMessage();

                //e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        //ErrorDialog(e.getMessage());
                        Toast ts;
                        ts = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        ts.show();
                    }
                });

                //e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
               errorMessage = e.getMessage();
                final String error = e.getMessage();

                //e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        //ErrorDialog(e.getMessage());
                        Toast ts;
                        ts = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        ts.show();
                    }
                });

                //e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {

                if(con!=null) {
                    con.disconnect();
                }

            }

            return resultObj;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And here's my event listener code in the login activity.

```
//when clicking the login button
    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //do now the login process
            userText.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
            passwordText.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
            tvRegister.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
            umlogo.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);


            //set textviews to invisible
           /* tv[0].setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
            tv[1].setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);*/

            //set also the button to invisible
            loginBtn.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);


            //set visible the progress bar
            pb.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);

            //set now the user login credentials
            credentials[0] = userText.getText().toString();
            credentials[1] = passwordText.getText().toString();
            loginTask = new LoginTask(credentials,"login");
            //loginTask.execute("http://10.0.2.2/sampleRequest.php");
            //loginTask.execute("http://10.0.2.2/motorpool_june_2016_laravel/public/mobile/login");


            loginTask.execute("http://128.199.105.49/mobile/login");

            //SessionHolder.login(credentials, la);

        }
    });
```

However it is still not working. Please help. :(

Comment: And the error is?!

Comment: It will force close the application. I am trying to catch the errors in order to avoid application force close... I am expecting to see a toast message but I only get a force close... Please help

Comment: Again, what is the stacktrace of the crash?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using AVD but instead generate automatically the APK and try it with Bluestack...

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare `String`s with `==` in java. You must write it like below:

```
if(this.privateRequest.equals("login")){
```

`==` tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object)

Comment: No ... That's not my problem.. I can login if there is an internet so it is not the problem.. The problem is if there is no internet it will force close the application and that's what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Add the logcat log in your question .

Comment: Unfortunately I do not use AVD.. When I am testing for an application, I jsut directly generate the APK then install it with Bluestack....

Comment: why ? this way you cant debug anything . use a android device and its log in logcat. you cant resolve your errors without the log

Comment: IT's because there is a problem with the AVD... Okay I will try it again with AVD and logcat in order to see the error exception.